# Querying all WPSE plugins

Tags: discussion, support

I'd expect that the search phrase [`"Plugin Name"`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Plugin%20Name%22) produced **a lot more** of results:

> [image]

If we try to restrict by answers, `"Plugin Name" is:a`, there are even less results: 17.

Why is that? My intention was to write in an Answer: *"look how many examples of custom (wpse crafted) plugins you can find in our site"*, only to find out that it seems impossible.

Comment: Something like `"plugin name:" is:answer`, perhaps?

Comment: Donnow what happened, I was sure having tried with the colon too... We can shorten the search with `is:a` and `is:q`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is (little) known bug in the search engine: you must include the colons.

A search for [code:"Plugin Name:"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=code:%22Plugin%20Name:%22) yields 699 results.
A search for just ["Plugin Name:"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Plugin%20Name:%22) yields 704 results.

Comment: Oh, I could swear I tried with the colon... a little bug on my side too :) Wasn't aware of the `code:` selector, thanks!